# Add new IP addresses in Ubuntu Server 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: networking, 18.04, netplan

I need to add new IP addresses to my server which runs Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS, then I realised that Ubuntu 18.04 changed network configuration to use [netplan](https://netplan.io/reference).

I read that all configurations are under /etc/netplan directory but in my system there is no file under that directory.

Where are my network configuration files, and how do I add new IP addresses there?

Comment: Are you using a GUI (NetworkManager) or is this a server install?  (In which case there should be a network configuration under the netplan folder)  Or is this server upgraded from an older Ubuntu?

Comment: @ThomasWard it's server install. It's installation not upgraded from an older version.

Comment: Can you do me a favor and see if there's networking defined in `/etc/network/interfaces` still on your system?  And is this a VPS with a prebuilt install image possibly?

Comment: @ThomasWard no it's not exist.

Comment: @ThomasWard it's dedicated from ovh servers.

Comment: Try checking /etc/network/interfaces.d instead of /etc/network/interfaces.  You can continue using ifupdown (with or without cloud-init driving it) on upgrade to 18.04, or you can deploy your new config under /etc/netplan.

Comment: @slangasek '/etc/network/interfaces.d': No such file or directory

Comment: The supported locations for network configuration on Ubuntu are /etc/network/interfaces, /etc/network/interfaces.d, /etc/netplan, and /run/netplan.  If you can't find your existing network configuration in any of these locations, then I don't know where the configuration lives.  Also, according to https://www.ovh.com/world/dedicated-servers/distributions/ Ubuntu 18.04 is not supported by OVH.  You may want to contact OVH support for help figuring out how the network is being configured in their environment since it doesn't appear to be using the standard Ubuntu tools.

Answer (score 0):

I researched more and found these;

My default network configuration is here: **/etc/systemd/network/50-default.network**

Main IP address, gateway and other things are resides in that file.
This explains strangeness that even **/etc/network/interfaces** not exist and **/etc/netplan** directory is empty, system is still running without problem.

This page helped me to add new IP addresses:

https://docs.ovh.com/gb/en/vps/network-ipaliasing-vps/#step-1-create-the-configuration-file

I created **50-cloud-init.yaml** file and fill it with these informations,

```
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        enp96s0f0:
            dhcp4: true
            match:
                macaddress: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
            set-name: enp96s0f0
            addresses:
            - 51.189.170.192/32
            - 51.189.170.193/32
            - 51.189.170.194/32
            - 51.189.170.195/32
            - 51.189.170.196/32
            - 51.189.170.197/32
            - 51.189.170.198/32
            - 51.189.170.199/32
            - 51.189.170.200/32
            - 51.189.170.201/32
            - 51.189.170.202/32
            - 51.189.170.203/32
            - 51.189.170.204/32
            - 51.189.170.205/32
            - 51.189.170.206/32
            - 51.189.170.207/32
```

Then run **netplan apply** and it's working now.